# A central location for catching throwables of JUnit tests?

Tags: selenium, junit

I would like to catch any throwable during a Selenium test e.g. in order to make a screenshot. The only solution I could come up with for now is to separately surround the test steps with a try and catch block in every test method as following:

```
    @Test
    public void testYouTubeVideo() throws Throwable {
        try {

            // My test steps go here


        } catch (Throwable t) {
            captureScreenshots();
            throw t;
        }
    }
```

I'm sure there is a better solution for this. I would like a higher, more centralized location for this try-catch-makeScreenshot routine, so that my test would be able to include just the test steps again. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare a `TestRule`, probably a [TestWatcher](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) or if you want to define the rules more explicitly, [ExternalResource](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html). This would look something like:

```
public class WatchmanTest {
    @Rule
    public TestRule watchman= new TestWatcher() {
        @Override
        protected void failed(Description d) {
            // take screenshot here
        }
    };

    @Test
    public void fails() {
        fail();
    }

    @Test
    public void succeeds() {
    }
}
```

The `TestWatcher` anonymous class can of course be factored out, and just referenced from the test classes.

Comment: What if you need to run a @After method both when failing and passing?

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem using [Spring's AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). In summary:

1. Declare the selenium object as a bean
2. Add an aspect using
   `@AfterThrowing`
3. The aspect can take the screenshot and save it to a
   file with a semirandom generated name.
4. The aspect also rethrows the exception, with the exception message including the filename so you can look at it afterwards.

I found it more helpful to save the HTML of the page due to flakiness of grabbing screenshots.